# Sorting an hash given an Array including information about the order criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to order a `Hash` of `Array`s by caring the order "stated"/"specified" in another `Array`. That is, for example, I have:

```
# This is the Hash of Arrays mentioned above.

hash = {
  1 => [
    "Value 1 1",
    "Value 1 2",
    "Value 1 n",
  ],
  2 => [
    "Value 2 1",
    "Value 2 2",
    "Value 2 n",
  ],
  3 => [
    "Value 3 1",
    "Value 3 2",
    "Value 3 n",
  ],
  m => [
    "Value m 1",
    "Value m 2",
    "Value m n",
  ]
}
```

and

```
# This is the Array mentioned above.

array = [m, 3, 1, 2]
```

*I would like to order `hash` keys as "stated"/"specified" in the `array` in order to have*:

```
# Note that Hash keys are ordered as in the Array.

ordered_hash = {
  m => [
    "Value m 1",
    "Value m 2",
    "Value m n",
  ],
  3 => [
    "Value 3 1",
    "Value 3 2",
    "Value 3 n",
  ],
  1 => [
    "Value 1 1",
    "Value 1 2",
    "Value 1 n",
  ],
  2 => [
    "Value 2 1",
    "Value 2 2",
    "Value 2 n",
  ]
}
```

**How can I make that** (maybe using the `Enumerable` Ruby module or some unknown to me Ruby on Rails method)**?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted_array = hash.sort_by { |k,v| array.index(k) }
```

If you want ordering and a Hash, you'll need to use ActiveSupport::OrderedHash, e.g.

```
sorted_array = hash.sort_by { |k,v| array.index(k) }
sorted_hash  = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash[sorted_array]
```

Comment: Note that Hashes are sorted by insertion order in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

On this toy example, James' method using `array.index` will be fine, but if the hash or array were large, you wouldn't want to do `.index` over and over. The more efficient way would be:

```
Hash[*array.map {|i| [i, hash[i]]}]
```